# Create Zip File Fedora 17

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip, fedora

Hi  I work with fedora 17 and I want to create zip file

There are four files in my directory /tmp/manager/

```
sos.prj
sos.shp  
sos.shx
sbb.shh
```

I want to  create zip file from    sos.prj,sos.shp,sos.shx files

I want to use `grep`. In other words, I want to create zip file from grep's result

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You want to use `grep` to create a zip file?

Comment: No. I want to create zip file from grep's result

Comment: Please explain your desire to use `grep`.  What `grep` result are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zip myArchiveName *.{prj,shp,shx}
```

This will zip all files with your extensions listed into a zip file named myArchiveName.zip

Answer (score 0):

People normally use `tar` and some archiver, examples:

```
tar czf manager.tar.gz /tmp/manager/
tar cjf manager.tar.bz2 /tmp/manager/
tar cJf manager.tar.xz /tmp/manager/
```

`.xz` format often yields the highest compression ratio and this is the compression format used for `.rpm` in Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the OP was thinking of using `grep` to find all the sos.* files but as @Impossibear says it's easier to just use a wildcard. If you want to focus on `sos` files, you could use `zip myArchive sos.*`